# Linux shell one liner launch script if file doesn't exist doesnt work

Tags: shell

For a all files in a specified directory with a specified filter `(png|gif|jpe?g)` (! with `\0` separator to avoid filenames with spaces problems), I wanted to see if the "optimized" `webp` file exists, and if *not*, convert it.

I know what follows can be optimized, etc. but I just want to make it work.

If you have a better solution (*with explanation!*) this can be interesting too, of course.

```
IFS= readarray -t -d '' tab < <(find . -type f -print0  | grep -zZE "(png|gif|jpe?g)$") && for f in "${tab[@]}"; do if [ ! -f "$f.webp" ]; then cwebp -q 80 "$f" -o "$f.webp"; fi done
```

Here's what I did: I'm making an array via `readarray` of all found files that match my pattern. Then I do a loop on them, where I test if the file exists. If not, I call `cwebp -q 80 "$f" -o "$f.webp";` This one doesn't work with the following errors. Why?

```
Error! Could not process file ./08/10700_header.jpg
Error! Cannot read input picture file './08/10700_header.jpg'
Error! Could not process file ./08/205790_header.jpg
Error! Cannot read input picture file './08/205790_header.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution in bash: you don't really need find:

```
shopt -s extglob  # extended pattern match, you likely already have it set
shopt -s globstar # extended directory level search ('**' matches any directory level)

for f in **/*.@(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)
do 
    [[ -f "$f.webp" ]] || cwebp -q 80 "$f" -o "$f.webp"
done
```

To run with `parallel` we have to get rid of the already done files so that we can call `cwebp` directly. A way is to filter the list of files with the list of webp files:

```
printf '%s\n' **/*.@(jpg|jpeg|png|gif) \
    | grep -vf <(printf '%s\n' **/*.webp | sed 's/\.webp$//') \
    | parallel -i cwebp -q 80 {} -o {}.webp
```

In slow-mo:

- `printf '%s\n' **/*.@(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)` generate the list of all possible candidates as a stream (since this is the `printf` built-i, in bash it is not command-line constrained)
- `grep -vf <(printf '%s\n' **/*.webp | sed 's/\.webp$//')` removes from that list all the files that already have an associated `.webp` (by listing the `*.webp` files, truncating their extension, and using the result as a `grep` pattern list)
- `parallel -i cwebp -q 80 {} -o {}.webp` feeds the result to parallel for execution.

Note that since `parallel` doesn't seem to have a parameter to take null-terminated input, you just have to hope that you haven't got weird filenames.

The pre-filtering technique can also be used for a non-parallel case.

Comment: Is it possible to launch it using `parallel`?

Comment: For your information, I had some corrupted jpg files and my script was working...

Comment: Yes, but your code was so contrived that you thought it was your code :)

Comment: Added suggestion for parallel execution

Comment: Quote: "Note that since parallel doesn't seem to have a parameter to take null-terminated input".... this is why I wont use `parallel`... but your suggestion is so good that if I could I would up your answer once again. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what produces the errors that you show or why, but presumably it's `cwebp` that is having issues finding the pathnames that you give it.

I would have let `find` find the relevant files and execute the loop rather than using `grep` and a temporary array:

```
find . \( -name '*.png' -o -name '*.gif' -o -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.jpeg' \) \
        -type f -exec sh -c '
        for pathname do
                [ -f "$pathname.webp" ] && continue
                cwebp -q 80 "$pathname" -o "$pathname.webp"
        done' sh {} +
```

Here, I use `find` as a sort of pathname generator for an in-line `sh -c` script.  The in-line script gets pathnames in batches and loops over them. For each given pathname, if the corresponding `.webp` file exists, the loop skips to the next pathname.  Otherwise, the `cwebp` command is invoked.

This avoids issues with strange file or directory names, and would be portable to any system that has `cwebp` installed (the `find` command itself is standard, as is the in-line script).

See also "[Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)" for more information about the `-exec sh -c '...' sh {} +` syntax.

If this still does not work, you may want to investigate the image files reported to make sure they are actually valid image files.